# Get a nested fields total count from a mongo collection with C#, MongoDb.Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a mongo collection, shown below :

[image]

**I am using C#, ASP .Net Core 2.0 MongoDB 3.6**

I need to get the count of those TopicVideo Object, which have videolinks value(at least not empty)

```
Count(distinct VideoLink) From TopicVideo Where videolink is not null
```

of it will be enough for me to check if **it starts with http or not**.

Here is a code, I have tried but not working.

```
var teahcersCollection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Teachers");
        return teahcersCollection.Count(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Regex("TopicVideo.VideoLink'", "/http.*/"));
```

Again, To clear, how to get the count of videoLink in this scenario?

**The Other thing**

And another thing, I am struggling too much with this type of queries and I want to query from the collection. please refer me any good step by step detailed documentation if you think available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following aggregation query:

```
var teachersCollection = database.GetCollection<Teacher>("Teachers");
var regexFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Regex("TopicVideo.VideoLink", "/^http/");
var httpBsonCount = teachersCollection.Aggregate()
    .Unwind(t => t.TopicVideo)
    .Match(regexFilter)
    .Group(new BsonDocument { { "_id", "null" }, { "count", new BsonDocument { { "$sum", 1 } } } })
    .ToList();

int httpCount = 0;
if (httpBsonCount.Any())
    httpCount = httpBsonCount.First()["count"].AsInt32;
```

Once executed the query, `httpCount` will contain your expected value.

In the mongo console, the query looks like:

```
db.Teachers.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$TopicVideo"},
    { $match: { "TopicVideo.VideoLink": /^http/ } },
    { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum : 1 } } }
]);
```

In order to learn about how to query MongoDB through C# driver I suggest you to follow the free [M101N course](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101N/about).

Comment: t.TopicVideo.VideoLink.StartsWith("http")); => here, TopicVideo itself another list. So the count have to be nested.

Comment: And its IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> type.

Comment: Sorry. My Mistake. Fixed.

Comment: In `.Unwund(t => t.TopicVideo), ` how can I get `TopicVideo`? as the teacherCollection is a BsonDocument, it will not recognize TopicVideo

Comment: See the updated code. I suggest you to have `teacherCollection` strongly typed. This way, your code is as much refactoring-friendly as possible. In case you cannot use such a strongly-typed collection, you should fall back to a BsonDocument to unwind (i.e. .Unwind("TopicVideo")).